# Downloading bin folder's dll file of ASP.Net App

Tags: asp.net

I just want to know , Is this possible to download my application's dll file from production server's bin directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via HTTP, if that's what you mean. You don't generally want to make that file available in that way.

If for some reason you want to make it available, like in some kind of code sharing scenario, I would code up a page that streams it out directly:

```
var fullQualifiedPathToDll = Server.MapPath("/") + "/bin/mydll.dll";

var myFileStream = new FileStream(fullQualifiedPathToDll, FileMode.Open);
var fileSize = myFileStream.Length;

var buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
myFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
myFileStream.Close();

Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Be VERY sure that this is what you want to do when you're doing it. This is adapted from a sample found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, no. ASP.NET blocks requests to the bin directory.

Comment: @Amit: Accessing the assemblies in the `Bin` folder is not possible via HTTP, but you can download it via FTP.